# r - Lag a data.frame by the number of NAs

Tags: r, function, apply, lag

In other words, I am trying to lag a data.frame that looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2  NA
3  3  3  3  NA NA
4  4  4  NA NA NA
5  5  NA NA NA NA
6  NA NA NA NA NA
```

To something that looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
1  NA NA NA NA NA
2  1  NA NA NA NA
3  2  1  NA NA NA
4  3  2  1  NA NA
5  4  3  2  1  NA
6  5  4  3  2  1
```

So far, I have used a function that counts the number of NAs, and have tried to lag my each column in my data.frame by the corresponding number of NAs in that column.

```
V1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
V2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA)
V3 <- c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA)
V4 <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA)
V5 <- c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA)
V6 <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
mydata <- cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6)
na.count <- colSums(is.na(mydata))
lag.by <- function(mydata, na.count){lag(mydata, k = na.count)}
lagged.df <- apply(mydata, 2, lag.by)
```

But this code just lags the entire data.frame by one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the columns with `apply` and append the NA elements first by subsetting the NA elements using `is.na` and then the non-NA element by negating the logical vector (`is.na`)

```
apply(mydata, 2, function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)]))
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#[1,]  1 NA NA NA NA NA
#[2,]  2  1 NA NA NA NA
#[3,]  3  2  1 NA NA NA
#[4,]  4  3  2  1 NA NA
#[5,]  5  4  3  2  1 NA
#[6,]  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  thanks, added some more description. Hope it helps

Comment: Why using `apply` instead of `lapply`?

Comment: @nicola The OP created a `matrix` if you check it in the example `mydata <- cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `sort` function with option `na.last = FALSE` like this:

**edit:**

Akrun's comment is a valid one. If the values need to stay in the order as they are in the data.frame, then Akrun's answer is the best. Sort will out everything in order from low to high with the NA's in front.

```
library(purrr)
map_df(mydata, sort, na.last = FALSE)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3     2     1    NA    NA    NA
4     4     3     2     1    NA    NA
5     5     4     3     2     1    NA
6     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

Or apply:

```
apply(mydata, 2, sort , na.last = FALSE)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
[1,]  1 NA NA NA NA NA
[2,]  2  1 NA NA NA NA
[3,]  3  2  1 NA NA NA
[4,]  4  3  2  1 NA NA
[5,]  5  4  3  2  1 NA
[6,]  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

**edit2:**

As nicolo commented. `order` can preserve the order of the variables.

```
mydata[,3] <- c(4, 3, 1, 2, NA, NA)
map_df(mydata, function(x) x[order(!is.na(x))])
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
  <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     3     2     4    NA    NA    NA
4     4     3     3     1    NA    NA
5     5     4     1     2     1    NA
6     6     5     2     3     2     1
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the order, you could use `order`: `map_df(mydata,function(x) x[order(!is.na(x))])`.

Comment: @nicola, added to the answer.